# I see in-app purchases in Firebase, but I don't see them in iTunes connect/AppAnnie

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase, in-app-purchase, firebase-analytics

On 6/16 in Firebase I see some in app purchases from 1 user in my Vampires iOS app. 2 for $19.99 each and 1 for $9.99. I don't see that in App Annie/iTunes connect.

For a different app, Pirates iOS, I see on 6/15 2 in-app purchase at a price of 3.30 each. In App Annie stats I see revenue of $4.15, but for for 6/16.

Looks like dates of in-app purchases are messed up/not reporting?

I also checked iTunes connect and AppAnnie reports for 6/17 and see no revenue for that day.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Also posted at the Google Group for Firebase first 2 days ago with no responses: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/firebase-talk/f0W8Gu0WlIQ/discussion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In-app purchases are not currently being validated by Firebase on iOS, and so it might be that these purchases are the result of piracy.  In that case, Firebase would report these purchases and iTunes (and, subsequently AppAnnie) would not.  This should addressed in an upcoming release of the SDK.

Comment: Is it still upcoming? Because I still have this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Firebase 3.5.1 should solve this.
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios

> "FEATURE Added a feature to validate the authenticity of in-app
>   purchase events before they are reported by Firebase Analytics."

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue.. high volume of purchase in Firebase and many (many) less in ITC / App Annie... and by the way, I don't think that it's a problem related to piracy..

**EDIT:** I think that probably Firebase track the trigger of the button i.e. when *updatedtransactions* is fired, and not when the purchase is actually *confirmed.*  So for example an User click the IAP button in the app and then *cancel* the operation. Maybe this activity is tracked by Firebase even if the purchase isn't happened.

Just my 2 cents.. I'll make some test and I will report here..